# Error in MATLAB when opening .mat files with Chinese characters written by savemat

Tags: python, matlab, character-encoding, scipy, mat-file

It looks like savemat is producing `.mat` files that MATLAB cannot open when they contain Chinese characters, but `loadmat` is able to:

```
$ python -c 'from scipy.io import *; savemat("tmp.mat", {"test": "你好"}); print(loadmat("tmp.mat")["test"])' && matlab -nodesktop -r 'load tmp; exit'
['你好']

To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

Error using load
Can't read file /home/tmp.mat.
```

Any ideas how I can either change `savemat` to output something MATLAB can open or change MATLAB settings such that I can read the files?

Comment: Octave error: >> load tmp.mat
warning: load: can not read multi-byte encoded UTF8 characters; replacing unreadable characters with '?'

Comment: yes got the same in Octave, but I dont see how I can fix it in matlab. Surely there must be a way to open .mat files with Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of [`savemat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html) and [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btox10b-1-version) I believe that `savemat` produces `.mat` files with an older format (what MATLAB calls `-v6`, that doesn't support Unicode (introduced in `-v7`).

You should be able to save `.mat` files of the newer format if you **switch from `savemat` to an HDF5 writer** like [`h5py`](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/) or [`hd5storage`](https://pypi.org/project/hdf5storage/). Alternatively, you can always store strings as byte arrays and interpret them later on.

See also: [Creating a .mat file of v7.3 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362831/creating-a-mat-file-of-v7-3-in-python), [Strings in HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html).